# Stateful Service Fabric Application Not Working In Azure For Free Trial Account

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful

I'm new to azure service fabric, and tried to setup one using a free trial account in azure. I created a service fabric cluster with a single node. Then I created an app in my local machine with one Stateless Web Service and a Stateful .NET Core Service. In my local machine, I can get everything working, but when I tried deploying it to azure, all stateless services are not working. I say this because, whenever I created an app with only a stateful service in there, it's still not working in azure.

The stateful service app as I monitored it from the Service Fabric Explorer it gives a warning as below image:

[image]

and after a warning, it will then turn into an error with the following message:

[image]

I tried finding solutions online but I found nothing. I read some articles saying that It could be a disk storage problem, but I don't know how to resolve this because in a Free Trial account, I think you have a limited storage.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What's the VM SKU of your cluster? Did you setup your cluster?

Go to your cluster via the azure portal, the name of the VMScale set would be the same name as with your cluster's node. Go to the VM Scaleset and check the SIZE in the overview. You might need to change / upscale your VM Scaleset

Comment: Thanks. Can I do that in a free account? I'll try that.

Comment: I'm not pretty sure what do you mean with a free account. You should have free credits at least. VM scalesets could cost a lot depending on the size.

Refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-capacity) for a good start to help you size up what you need.